# Add list as a value to a python dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have two lists

```
listA = [3,45,23,7]
listB = [34,76,21,76]
```

And a function that takes in items from these lists and returns either true or false

```
def function(itemA,itemB):
    # does something
    # returns true or false
```

I loop over these lists and want to add to a dictionary each item in listA as a key. As a value to that key I want to add a new listC. How do I do that? The below doesn't work

```
newDict = {}
for itemA in listA:
    listC = []
    for itemB in listB:
        if function(itemA,itemB):
            listC.append(itemB)
    newDict[itemA] = listC
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is quite a general statement. What doesn't work? What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Comment: This codes seems fine, can you post your traceback? Also, don't name your variables `dict`, it's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: You say that you want to have each item in ListA as a value. But your code does otherwise. Your listA items become the key and the ListC becomes the value. Can you tell which of your statements is correct?

Comment: It would help a lot if you were to post what `function` does and the output that you expect

Comment: You guys are right, it is working. I don't know why it didn't work first hand. I guess posting it on here, straightened out some mistake. I guess this can be closed. Sorry about that.

Comment: The problem stated in the question didn't actually exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated your code runs fine, but it does the same thing as this comprehension:

```
d = {a: [b for b in listB if function(a, b)] for a in listA}
```

---

(I used as an example `def function(a, b): return a < b`.)

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure that I understand your question correctly (and I would be more helpful if I knew what `function` does), but is this what you’re looking for:

```
answer = {}
for itemA, itemB in itertools.product(listA, listB):
  if function(itemA, itemB):
    answer.setdefault(itemA, []).append(itemB)
```